# OpenERP square feet UOM

Tags: odoo

Suppose i'm a reseller of tiles, and I have a tile (single product) that is 1' x 3'. This tile is not further dividable (to OpenERP / at this level), since we only ship tiles.

However, we'd like the salesperson to enter in the quantity needed in square feet, to cover a room for example. If a customer enters in 3 square feet, we'd ship them one tile, five square feet, two tiles, nine square feet, three tiles, ten, four tiles.

My question is what is the best way to present this data in OpenERP?

It seems that creating a new 'sqft' UoM category would work, but then I cannot convert this back into PCE. I could define a second PCE in the same UoM category, but then I have two PCEs (one for 'normal' products, one for tiles, and never the twain shall meet). In addition, this is not scalable: if i'm also selling a 1' by 4' tile, i'd need another UoM category and conversion factor (one category / factor per tile size)

I have a custom ordering interface (we are not actually using OpenERP's frontend for this), and could do the proper conversions there. However, this then presents a data mismatch - in OpenERP, our product's UoM (and buying UoM, since we resell) are expressed in PCE, but we need a new concept of an 'selling UoM' and connected conversion factor.

The question is, is that last method (everything in OpenERP stays in PCE, OpenERP knows nothing about sales order UoM) the recommended manner in which to approach this?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in two ways:

1. Set the uos_coeff field in the product, and set uos_id != uom_id.

   You can define two different UoM for Sale and Purchase of same product, and define the coefficient to make the conversion.
2. Define two different product with two different UoM and define a BOM with the relation between them, so when you sell one product other will also consumed.

Comment: This does not fix the root of the problem, which will be having multiple PCE UoM. Unless you intend me to add the sqft UoM to the pice category, which doesn't exactly make sense.

Comment: did you look at the uom_coeff this coefficient makes the conversion between two different UOM that are in different categories. like buying product with square meter and selling in pcs. Creating many PCE UOM seems quiet wrong.

Comment: Okay, it does seem to exist in OpenERP 6.1. However, there is this in product.template: `_constraints = [
    (_check_uom, 'Error: The default UOM and the purchase UOM must be in the same category.', ['uom_id']),
]` which then checks `if product.uom_id.category_id.id <> product.uom_po_id.category_id.id`. So even though it appears that it may work, OpenERP 6.1 is by default not allowing me to set that.

Comment: Further checking proves that the constraint also exists in 7.0. Do you know why this constraint exists? Also, the field is uos_coeff, which is why I didn't notice it earlier.

Comment: Ah, I see, never mind. You're right. There are three UOM per product: uom_id, uom_po_id, uos_id. The constraint is for the first two.